# How to use same FileOutputStream for different files

Tags: java

I have an application which create dozens of files per second.
Each file has different name.
For each file I'm creating new FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);
...
fos.close();
```

Is there a way to avoid from creating a lot of FileOutputStreams ?
How can I use same FileOutputStream to create different files ?

(I want to minimize the work of the gc)

Thanks

Comment: Try to use pool of `FileChannels` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

Comment: Writing to a file is several orders of magnitude slower than creating and collecting instances of FileOutputStream. You're trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be optimized. No, it's not possible to use a single FileOutputStream for several files.

Comment: The GC was created so you wouldn't have to worry about it.